# GitLab pod. Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.233.124.46:8005/health_check

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

Use https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/kubernetes/gitlab_omnibus.html#configuring-and-installing-gitlab for install GitLab. But I have a problem.

I see in describe gitlab pod: `Warning  Unhealthy              1m (x195 over 39m)  kubelet, k8s-m3.me  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.233.105.52:8005/health_check?token=SXBAQichEJasbtDSygrD: dial tcp 10.233.105.52:8005: getsockopt: connection refused`

Kubernetes v1.10.2

```
# kubectl get pods -owide
NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
gitlab1-gitlab-75576c4589-7dvlm             0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   92         9h        10.233.105.52   k8s-m2.me
gitlab1-gitlab-postgresql-f66555d65-dk5v6   1/1       Running            0          9h        10.233.78.175   k8s-m1.me
gitlab1-gitlab-redis-58cf598657-mqs2w       1/1       Running            0          9h        10.233.124.48   k8s-m3.me
gitlab1-gitlab-runner-555b89f44b-7vgwm      0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   100        9h        10.233.105.51   k8s-m2.me
```

I see problem in next log (full log https://gist.github.com/IvanBiv/9a89024f5cd4a1207070badd025bf57c):

```
# kubectl describe pod gitlab1-gitlab-75576c4589-7dvlm
...
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                -------
  Normal   Pulled     58m (x84 over 9h)   kubelet, k8s-m2.me  Container image "gitlab/gitlab-ce:10.6.2-ce.0" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy  9m (x1709 over 9h)  kubelet, k8s-m2.me  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.233.105.52:8005/health_check?token=SXBAQichEJasbtDSygrD: dial tcp 10.233.105.52:8005: getsockopt: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    4m (x1064 over 8h)  kubelet, k8s-m2.me  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Gitlab Runner log

```
# kubectl logs gitlab1-gitlab-runner-555b89f44b-7vgwm
+ cp /scripts/config.toml /etc/gitlab-runner/
+ /entrypoint register --non-interactive --executor kubernetes
Running in system-mode.

ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=tQtCbx5U status=couldn't execute POST against http://gitlab1-gitlab.default:8005/api/v4/runners: Post http://gitlab1-gitlab.default:8005/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 10.233.49.21:8005: i/o timeout
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Services

```
# kubectl get services -owide
NAME                                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                      AGE       SELECTOR
gitlab1-gitlab                                        ClusterIP   10.233.49.21    <none>        22/TCP,8065/TCP,8105/TCP,8005/TCP,9090/TCP   9h        name=gitlab1-gitlab
gitlab1-gitlab-postgresql                             ClusterIP   10.233.60.177   <none>        5432/TCP                                     9h        name=gitlab1-gitlab-postgresql
gitlab1-gitlab-redis                                  ClusterIP   10.233.43.12    <none>        6379/TCP                                     9h        name=gitlab1-gitlab-redis
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of times we had this issue. Instead of health check, we started to use login page where it sends 200. Use the context path below

- /users/sign_in

Comment: Ok, how I can fix It?

Comment: It was deploy with Helm.

Comment: great question. Download the charts and then redeploy it. https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-omnibus from your local. Be careful it is in alpha version.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/tree/master There is recommend in production gitlab-omnibus...why?

Comment: I clone "https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-omnibus.git", and try call 
"/gitlab-omnibus# helm install --name gitlab1 -f ../values.yaml ." And I see:
"Error: found in requirements.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: gitlab-runner"

Comment: May be better way to use "https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab", may be this project can will get production level?

Comment: I change check heath path, I see: "Warning  Unhealthy              1m (x24 over 5m)  kubelet, k8s-m1.me  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.233.78.179:8005/users/sign_in: dial tcp 10.233.78.179:8005: getsockopt: connection refused". I try call "curl http://10.233.78.179/users/sign_in", result: "Connection refused"

Comment: I fix it "Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.233.105.52:8005/health_check?token=SXBAQichEJasbtDSygrD: dial tcp 10.233.105.52:8005: getsockopt: connection refused" with set in file "templates/gitlab/gitlab-deployment.yaml" in repository "https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-omnibus" next: in region livenessProbe and readinessProbe value "initialDelaySeconds: 420".